# Intellij Idea Select Home Directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ Idea 12.04 Installed.
When I look up the tutorials online they all say when I go to <kbd>New Project</kbd>-><kbd>Project SDK</kbd>-><kbd>New..</kbd>-><kbd>JDK</kbd> I should see In `C:\Program Files\Java` I should see two folders: `jre7` and `jdk1.7.0_13`. I should choose the `jdk1.7.0_13` as my Home Directory for JDK. But I only have the `jre7` folder and I have installed JDK update 45(Latest). What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable `JDK_HOME` and point it to your installed JDK home.

Comment: Open Start -> Computer -> Properties -> Environment and add variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed JDK update 45(Latest). What should I do?

Install JDK 7 update 45 or the latest and use that as your JDK.

I found the link using google for `JDK download`

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: @MartinVelichkov Then you don't have it.  Or you need to click the refresh button ;)

Comment: If all you see is `jre7` in explorer either you installed it somewhere else (I would check both `Program Files` directories), or you didn't install the JDK, only the JRE.

Comment: I have it now, what do I do next? Which directory to chose for home directory for JDK

Comment: The top level directory with the jdk-1.7.0_xx